# Converting UTF-16LE to UTF-8 in PHP - latin extended

Tags: php, encoding, iconv

I am trying to convert a UTF-16LE txt file to UTF-8.

I found a possible solution here on Stackoverflow and tried the following two:

```
 iconv($in_charset = 'UTF-16LE' , $out_charset = 'UTF-8' , $str);
```

and

```
 mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF8', 'UTF-16LE');
```

This seems to be working, unfortunately only partially. The problem seems to be that I am trying to convert a txt file that is in Czech, which uses Latin extended characters, such as š, č, ř, ž, Š, Č, Ř, ě etc., i.e. letters from the Czech alphabet, which is much longer than the English one. And unfortunately all these non-English characters are encoded incorrectly. Is there any way around this to convert these correctly as well?

I thought about str_replace for the converted text, but the problem is that some of the above are not converted to "weird symbols", but instead to other letters such as "q" or "+" sign, which means that if I replace them, it would also replace all "q" letters or "+" symbols, which is not what I want.

Here are all the possible non-English characters that we use in Czech:

```
 ěščřžýáíéťůúňĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉŮÚŤŇ
```

Comment: Latin extended is possibly not UTF-8. So just use the correct name for the file you have. Note: I think your problem is not about UTF-8. but downstream. If you put your character in a string (as `&#` entity, to be sure your editor, and webserver is not changing encoding) and you print them. Are they correct?

Comment: Do you mean that your input stream is incorrectly encoded and mixes characters in UTF-16 LE and some Latin single byte encoding (maybe ISO 8859-2)? If that's the case, it's going to be hard to fix on your side. Any chance of getting it addressed at the source?

Comment: Hi, not sure, but UTF-8 does support all the Czech characters, it is the encoding I use all the time, even in HTML meta tag I put utf-8 and all the Czech characters are displayed correctly.

Comment: So what I have is a text file in UTF-16LE. I am trying to convert it to UTF-8. I use the iconv command and then in webpage meta tag I have utf-8, to which I also converted the UTF-16LE. On the webpage I see all the characters correctly, except for the latin extended ones. Also if I try  eg. echo "ščř", these are shown correctly on the website in utf-8, so it must be the conversion that does not convert these correctly.

Comment: You don't need to guess. You can inspect the exact raw bytes either with [bin2hex()](https://php.net/bin2hex) or an [hexadecimal editor](https://hexed.it).

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].. Where the `$str` string comes from? Why do you think that its encoding differs from `UTF-8` (the PHP's internal character encoding)? And add some examples to illustrate your declaration _… This seems to be working, unfortunately only partially_. BTW, your enumeration of Czech accented letters seems to be incomplete (`ď Ď ó Ó`) [grin]…

Comment: You can use the function from this article [How can a byte sequence with unknown coding be made available as input for PHP?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028433/how-can-a-byte-sequence-with-unknown-coding-be-made-available-as-input-for-php/65028434#65028434) to display content from your file in a reproducible manner.